# Qt windows libmysql.dll

Tags: mysql, qt, dll, build

I have installed `MySQL 5.1.49` and the `binary QT 4.6.2 for Visual Studio 2008`. I configured Qt as follow:

```
C:\Qt>configure -static -no-webkit -plugin-sql-sqlite -plugin-sql-mysql -I C:\mysql\include -L C:\mysql\lib\optC:\Qt\src\plugins\sqldriver
```

Everything went fine, no errors. When I run `nmake` on my application everything runs fine, no errors as well. However when I execute my application under the debug folder I get a popup saying `"Driver not loaded"` (I have `QT += sql` under my `project.pro`)

If I goto `C:\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers` I dont see any `libmysql`, or any `*mysql.dll` only `qsqlmysql.obj and qsqlmysqld.obj` (there are files such as: `qsqlite4.dll, qsqlpsql4.dll` etc.)

I did try to build it manually by doing:

```
cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql
C:\Qt\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\mysql\include" "LIBS+=C:\mysql\lib\opt\libmysql.lib" mysql.pro
nmake
```

Everything compiles fine, no errors. However, I still don't find any libmysql.dll generated. Only file found is under `C:\mysql\bin\libmySQL.dll`

I have all the includes for MySQL under `C:\mysql\include` and the libraries under `C:\mysql\lib\opt`

Any ideas what could be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `-static` prevents you from using plugins at runtime. You will need to change

```
-plugin-sql-mysql
```

to

```
-qt-sql-mysql
```

and have it compiled in.

B1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using qt source instead of the binary one? I had a similar issue, however I was getting compile errors.